# Unable to get Total Rate printed using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php form, where I have four fields namely- Rate, Charged Rate, Excess and Charged Excess. Now out of these 4, 2 are non editable(Rate & Excess) and rest are editable fields(Charged Rate & Charged Excess).
Now the values in the non-editable fields are both echoing php values from a table and the editable ones are too. But the only difference is that the user can edit the lower editable fields to change the value of price entered.
The fifth field "Due_Amount" echoes value that the customer has to pay after applying series of calculations.

What I want is that when the editable fields are edited the "Due_Amount" which has the values echoed into it from calculation also change real-time when entered.
I hve written a javascript code to do that but for some reason, it is'nt printing or doing anything. Here is the code for js.

```
function balance()
    {
    var bal = alert('<?php echo $balance; ?>');
    console.log(bal);
    }

function charge()
{
    var rateCharged = alert('<?php echo $charge; ?>');

}

function excess()
{
    var excess = alert('<?php echo $excess;?>')
    }


function rateCharged()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["returnform"];
     var rateCharged = theForm.elements["rate_charged"];
    var howmany = 0;
    if(rate_charged.value!="")
    {
        howmany=parseInt(rate_charged.value);
       }
        return howmany;
}

function excessCharged()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["returnform"];
    var excessCharged = theForm.elements["charged_excess"];
    var how_many = 0;
    if(charged_excess.value!="")
    {
        how_many=parseInt(charged_excess.value);
        }
        return how_many;
}

function calculateTotal()
  {
    var balance = balance() + ((charge() + excess()) -(rateCharged() + excessCharged()));
    console.log(balance);
    document.getElementById('due_amount').value = balance;
    //console.log(bal);
}
```

And here is the php where it is called

```
<form action="return_book.php" id="returnform" method="post">
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';
include 'login_check.php';
$id1 = $_GET['id1'];
 $id2 = $_GET['id2'];
//echo $id1;// bookid
//echo $id2; // user id
```

.....lines of other code

```
days = $diff->format("%a");

            if($days > 0 and $due_date <= $date_in)
             {
                $excess = floor($EXCESS_CHARGE_RATE*$charge*$days);
                $balance = $balance - $excess;
                if ($balance >= 0)
               {
                    $due_amount = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $due_amount = -1 * ($balance);
                }
            }
            else {
                $excess = 0;
                    if ($balance >=0)
                    { $due_amount = 0 ;
                    }
                    else
                  { $due_amount = 1 * ($balance);
               }
           }
```

Rate Of Book

```
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="charge" disabled value = "<?php echo $charge?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "paid_err">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="rate_charged">Rate Charged</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="rate_charged" onchange="calculateTotal()" value = "<?php echo $charge?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "charged_rate_err">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group"></div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="charge">Balance</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="balance" disabled value = "<?php echo $balance?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "balance_err">
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="control-group"></div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="excess"><div style="color:red">Excess</div></label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="excess" name = "excess" disabled value = "<?php echo $excess;?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "paid_err">
                </div>
            </div>


             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="excess_charged">Excess Charged</label>

                <div class="controls">

                    <input type="text" id="charged_excess" name = "charged_excess" onchange="calculateTotal()"  value = "<?php echo $excess;?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "charged_excess_err">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group"></div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="">Due Amount</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name = "due_amount" id="due_amount"  value = "<?php echo $due_amount?>" placeholder=""><div style="color:red;" id = "due_amount_err">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any sort of help is welcome. I have even tried viewing console for some errors of print statements, but no success! There is nothing i see on the front end yet

Comment: var bal = <?php echo $balance; ?>  NOT USE IN ALERT

Comment: Nope, still not working. I get an error like "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<"